# Standalone, single purpose Waze / Gmaps with Android Things?

Tags: android, maps

I'd like to build a minimal, barebones device that uses "alert" data from either Gmaps or Waze.

The primary goals of this are:

- Putput of "alerts" - traffic / speed cameras
- Barebones, cut down OS, no other apps
- Hard-installed, i.e plugged in and left running in car / on ignition

Ideally, I'd like to run this on something like the Pi Zero, but I see minimum spec for Things is Rpi3 - seems a bit overkill, but I can live with that.

Think of this as a "Waze / Gmaps box" - it doesn't need to do anything else, no screen, no UI, no apps - just output alerts from the data. Alternatively, think of it like a "RoadAngel", speaker, couple of LED's maybe.

I'm thinking Android Things would be the way to go, but was looking Android Automotive too, which again would seem a bit overkill, as it's never going to need to integrate with car hardware etc?

Comment: Access to data would be via BT from my phone or Wifi Direct. Could also get a GPS-hat for a sim for the device, once proof of concept confirmed. 

Will probably also need it's own GPS-hat etc. 

Config, settings, preference etc would be set at install / creation, so no UI needed.